# The correct use of I or me

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct way to say?:

Her mother, her family and I
or
I, her mother and her family

Comment: Dup of the recent [Use of a pronoun with another person](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233980/use-of-a-pronoun-with-another-person).

Answer (score 0):

Offering an answer because I know, I'm new, and it might not be a dupe? :)

*"The correct use of I or me"
"What is the correct way to say?:
 Her mother, her family and I or I, her mother and her family"*

You've suggested two different questions here, which I presume was a typo, but to answer both implied questions:

Both "Her mother, her family and I" and "I, her mother, and her family" are correct. (As would be: "Her mother, her family and me" and "me, her mother, and her family"; in this case word order is not important.)

If you're asking about using "I" vs. "me", it doesn't matter what order the words are in (see above), only what part of speech they are. Subject is "I", object is "me".

"*Her mother, her family, and I* like John." ("*We* like John." = I)

"John likes *her mother, her family, and me.*" ("John likes *us*." = me)

Helps? (I offer the "we"/"us" example because any native speaker actually knows the difference between a subject and object, they just may not know to call it that. That's one of the few uses in English that's both very common and requires a clear difference in word choice.)

[Source: Professional Proofreader and Grammar Geek for twenty years, raised by same. :)]

Comment: It _has_ been answered before (and really shouldn't have been even then). You've missed out the situation where the phrase is a complement: normally nowadays 'It was her mother, her family and me.'